# Get url parent param in a child view in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to configure my project to use for multiple enterprises. I mean an user can be the manager of one and client in another. The user can select the enterprise that wants like this:
[image]

So I need to put the urls according to the enterprise in use, for example:

At the kiriosnet enterprise:

- www.kinet.com/kiriosNet/index
- www.kinet.com/kiriosNet/new_order/ . .

At the checkcell enterprise

- www.kinet.com/checkcell/index
- www.kinet.com/checkcell/new_order/
- www.kinet.com/checkcell/employees/

And so on ...

I use a intermediate model to select the rol using django groups:

```
class UsuarioEmpresa(models.Model):
    usuario = models.ForeignKey('Usuario')
    empresa = models.ForeignKey(Empresa)
    rol = models.ForeignKey(Group)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "UsuarioEmpresa"
        verbose_name_plural = "UsuariosEmpresas"

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s de %s" %(self.usuario, self.empresa)
```

I'm trying like this, in my global urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    # Enterprise admin
    url(r'^(?P<enterprise_name>[\w]+)/', include([
        url(r'^', include('app.urls')),
        url(r'^reparaciones/', include('reparaciones.urls', namespace='reparaciones')),
        url(r'^usuarios/', include('usuarios.urls', namespace='usuarios')),
        url(r'^equipos/', include('equipos.urls', namespace='equipos')),
        url(r'^empresas/', include('empresas.urls', namespace='empresas')),
        url(r'^reportes/', include('reportes.urls', namespace='reportes')),
    ]))
```

]

And the app urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
    # The home page
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    ...
]
```

My `views.py` on app index is:

```
# Index user loged in
@login_required
def index(request, enterprise_name):
    enterprise = Empresa.objects.filter(name__icontains = 'enterprise_name')
```

And I got the following error trying `http://127.0.0.1:8000/kiriosNet/`

```
NoReverseMatch at /kiriosNet/
Reverse for 'index' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not 
found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P<enterprise_name>[\\w]+)/$']
```

How advisable is use an bolean field "active" in my intermediate model to select the actual enterprise? I'm thinking do that now.

Comment: What is confusing you about this? You need to pass a value for `enterprise_name`. You haven't shown enough of your code to tell where that should come from.

Comment: Also, I don't think you should start all of your sub URLS with `^`, because that means "start of string" and should therefore not appear in sub-URLs.

Comment: @DanielRoseman the value is passed by the url: "kirios" or "checkcell". The problem is don't find the url.

Comment: @Ralf I will try removing the ^ to the sub urls. Thanks.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I've updated the description now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are attempting to do is called **multy-tenancy**, and there is a very good library for that called [django-tenant-schema](https://django-tenant-schemas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

It works by storing the data of different clients in different schemas in the same database. It requieres a model to be in charge of managing this schema switching:

```
from django.db import models
from tenant_schemas.models import TenantMixin

class Client(TenantMixin):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    paid_until =  models.DateField()
    on_trial = models.BooleanField()
    created_on = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

    # default true, schema will be automatically created and synced when it is saved
    auto_create_schema = True
```

I have tried and it works very smoothly.

Comment: As I understand, mi tenant is an enterprise, and I would share the data with the clients and TenantMixin would do the job to admin the urls? I'm right?

Comment: You are right, you can let **django-tenant-schema** to deal with it.

Comment: It works like a **charm**! So much thanks to you. I am doing things correctly right now.

Comment: You're welcome. I'll appreciate you to select my answer. Happy coding!!

Comment: Hi again @HuLu . I need one suggestion to deploy my app. I use Herok to deploy my apps but it does not work with multi tenancy posrgres schemas. Do you know another IAAS or solution for this? There is not enough documentation at Heroku to do this, I have tried everything with no results. I would appreciate your help.

Comment: I don't know what is your problem exactly, and I have never tried this with Heroku, but a fast search in Google gave me several clues, like this: https://github.com/bernardopires/django-tenant-schemas/issues/591. I realize it is a configuration issue of some sort.

Answer (score 1):

You should give a parameter to the requested URL.

```
@login_required
def index(request, empresa_name):
    Instance = ModelName.objects.filter(slug=empresa_name)
```

Posting from phone

Comment: The parameter is passed in the url, is the enterprise name: "kirios" or "checkcell". But Django don't find the url and show "Reverse not found".

Comment: Don't get me wrong but machines are dummy by nature. You have to tell them EXACTLY what to do. You can pass id as an argument in index function and change the urltoo, or you have to make a slug field in the model and pass the same name(empresa_name) in the url. Take a look here: https://github.com/skerdilajdhoxha/bloggerista/tree/master/socializing/posts

Comment: Thanks @skerdilajd. The next step is query the enterprise to my model like `enterprise = Enterprise.objects.filter(string__contains='enterprise_name')`, or save a short name in my model, that is easy. My trouble is configure the pattern to my view, and all views for all apps.